# How can I know if a ModalViewController is being shown?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I override -orientationChanged in my main ViewController to push ModalViewController A when the device is in landscape mode.  When placed back in portrait mode, ModalViewController A is dismissed.  However, there are other cases (after button touches) where ModalViewControllers B, C, or D are shown.  When those are showing, if the device is turned landscape and turned back, ModalViewController B C or D is dismissed, inappropriately.

I can verify that -orientationChanged on my main ViewController is being messaged even when a ModalViewController is shown.  Is there a condition I can add to my -orientationChanged method to bypass that code when ModalViewController B C or D is being shown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the modalViewController property in your main viewcontroller is one of your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I used the conditional: if([self.modalViewController isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to find what is the last ModalViewController.

```
UIViewController *leafController = self;
while(true) {
    if (leafController.modalViewController) {
        leafController = leafController.modalViewController;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
[leafController presentModalViewController:showController animated:YES];
```